Visitor account and unspecified Edge error persistence
we have a weird quirk with a network visitor account deployed to one of our computer labs. We have a restricted account that will launch into edge kiosk mode to an exam portal, with navigation, other apps, and other sites restricted. The edge session has been made a simple non-inprivate kiosk mode shortcut as we had issues with chrome and inprivate, however, we are experiencing an issue with sign ins.
When a user enters their account details incorrectly and becomes locked out, or on a different page, enters their access code incorrectly, edge will display the error. However, after unlocking the account or using the correct code, the error message continues to display. This continues even after reboot, across different PCs, for the same supplied username or access code. I have never seen this behaviour on a guest account.
I am at a loss as to what to even google to diagnose the error. And I don't think I can blame DNS but if there is a way to blame DNS please let me know.

developmer mode is also your favorite thing in this case... did you used it?

the error message continues to display. what error message and what happens after that? Does the logon succeed? Do they need to dismiss the error?

@GregAskew it provides the same error message that first occurred, and will not sign in or proceed. It is as though it is caching the response and won't let you proceed.
